# Eerie music in the Nexus

Tags: demons-souls

I'm in the Nexus in *Demon's Souls* and have progressed fairly far through the game. I've just completed World 4, the Shrine of Storms.

I've noticed some quite eerie organ music playing in the Nexus that I'm pretty sure doesn't exist at the beginning of the game. What is the reason for this change? Does it mean anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The music changes after you defeat 3 archdemons (world bosses).

http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/forum/t-225035/nexus-changed-music

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/954345-/62445580